# Need feedback on react hooks implementation

Tags: reactjs

I've gone through the docs in a fair bit of detail and understand that a setState function can be passed a function if the previous state is needed.

Here I am trying to, based on the state of a variable, set the state of another variable. This seems logically correct to me, but just feel weird. Looking for someone to sanity check it.

```
export default function Comp(props) {
  const [command, setCommand] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState(allowedTags);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    setCommand((prevCommand) => {
      if (command !== prevCommand) {
        const items = syncFunc(allowedTags, command);
        setItems(items);
      }
      return command
    });
  });
}
```

I also understand that this effect will run after every render. But will the effect cause itself to be scheduled to run again since it is updating state?

Comment: "I am trying to, based on the state of a variable, set the state of another variable" do you really need to have the second variable in state? MB you could simply compute `items = syncFunc(allowed, command)` once you need it in render or use `useMemo` if the computation is really expensive.

Comment: "But will the effect cause itself to be scheduled to run again since it is updating state?" updating the state will cause component to rerender so the effect will run again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YuryTarabanko this does not belong on code review unless it's a request to review code that the asker asserts is working as intended. The asker is questioning whether this code is correct at all, so it does not belong on code review.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I disagree because "This seems logically correct to me, but just feel weird." Sounds like a code review request to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook can be invoked in every **re-render** or only **once**, it is dependent on its implementation with an **array of dependencies**. more on [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) documentation.

It can also cause a re-render since you use the `setState` function in the `useEffect` and it causes changes on the state variables.

But there are some points with your implementation:

1. don't use the nested callback method to set your state variables since the `setState` method is an asynchronous action and you are trying to call an async action in another async action, which may cause an infinity re-render. in the end, debugging with such implementation need more time than usual (increasing complexity of the application).
2. you forgot to pass the variables as an array of dependency in the `useEffect` hook.  with this implementation, your hook will trigger on every re-render which is not your expectation.
3. with current implementation, `setCommand` method will call on every re-render but the body of your `if` statement will not invoke since you are trying to compare two equal variables together.

Comment: Thanks. For point 3. are you saying it will never invoke? My understanding is that if a rerender is caused by setCommand that ran elsewhere in the codebase, it will cause the if block above to evaluate. Is this not correct?

Comment: let's clarify, I mean that your **command** and **prevCommand** is always equal together, so this statement **command !== prevCommand** is always return false and prevent the if block to run. it's not about re-rendering by state changes or anything else.  @saq7